# DropDownList sets wrong SelectedValue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to set the value of an unbound DropDownList based on values passed in a query string.  Here is my code:

```
ListItem item = null;
            for (int x = 0; x < 60; x++)
            {
                item = new ListItem(x.ToString("D2"), x.ToString("D2"));
                ddStartMinutes.Items.Add(item);
                ddEndMinutes.Items.Add(item);
                if (x < 24)
                {
                    ddStartHours.Items.Add(item);
                    ddEndHours.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }

        if (Request.QueryString.Count > 5)
        {
            string startDate = Request.QueryString["startDate"];
            string startHour = Request.QueryString["startHour"];
            string startMin = Request.QueryString["startMin"];
            string endDate = Request.QueryString["endDate"];
            string endHour = Request.QueryString["endHour"];
            string endMin = Request.QueryString["endMin"];
            string cabinet = Request.QueryString["cabinet"];

            txtStartDate.Text = startDate;
            txtEndDate.Text = endDate;
            ddStartHours.SelectedValue = startHour;
            ddStartMinutes.SelectedValue = startMin;
            ddEndHours.SelectedValue = endHour;
            ddEndMinutes.SelectedValue = endMin;
            ddCabinets.SelectedValue = cabinet;

            runReport();
        }
```

I start by building the dropdown lists, then try to set the selected values based on the query string.  All the dropdowns get set to the value of endMin instead of their correct value.

If I debug and add a break point just before runReport(); I see that each of the string variables has the correct value from the query string, but each of the DropDownList selectedValues is set to endMin rather than its query string value.

For example, if in the query string startHour is 1, startMin is 2, endHour is 3 and endMin is 4, then each of the string variables get set from the query string correctly, but the dropdown selected values all get set to 4.

I'm pretty well stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this happens because you share items between the dropdowns

Comment: Very good point Amiram; if you share items between drop downs; selecting an item in ddStartHours would also select the same item in ddEndHours (and vice versa)

Comment: Amiram-- That is indeed the problem! I copied the item = new ListItem line before each Add, and it solved the problem.

If you add that as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with sharing `ListItem`s between dropdowns. To fix it use:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 60; x++) 
{ 
    var value = x.ToString("D2");
    ddStartMinutes.Items.Add(new ListItem(value, value));
    ddEndMinutes.Items.Add(new ListItem(value, value));
    if (x < 24) 
    { 
        ddStartHours.Items.Add(new ListItem(value, value));
        ddEndHours.Items.Add(new ListItem(value, value));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks lot. I had same issue and solve my problem with your answer. C# sometimes act illogical. There is nothing like issue in PHP. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a "deficiency" in DropDownList.  I use this extension to get around it:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the selected item by value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="list">Drop down list to select value on</param>
    /// <param name="value">Value to select</param>
    public static void SetSelectedByValue(this DropDownList list, string value)
    {
        var listItem = list.Items.FindByValue(value);
        if (listItem != null)
        {
            list.SelectedIndex = list.Items.IndexOf(listItem);
        }
    }
```

Usage in your provided source:

```
            ddStartHours.SetSelectedByValue(startHour);
            ddStartMinutes.SetSelectedByValue(startMin);
            ddEndHours.SetSelectedByValue(endHour);
            ddEndMinutes.SetSelectedByValue(endMin);
            ddCabinets.SetSelectedByValue(cabinet);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following

```
ddStartHours.Items.FindByValue(startHour).Selected = true;
```

this should set the value properly, though the extension above is doing this you can do it in one line in your above code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know that the value passed in via the query string will always be in the drop down list, you could do something like this:

`ddStartHours.Items.FindByValue(startHour) = true;`

To be on the safe side; you could always add in a null check like this:

```
var item = ddStartHours.Items.FindByValue(startHour);
if(item != null)
     item.Selected = true;
```

EDIT:

On second look; it seems like the shared items between drop downs is the cause.  If you have `ListItem1` and you add it to both `ddStartHours` and `ddEndHours`; selecting one will also select the other.

I'd probably refactor it out to have a static method that returns a collection of ListItems for both hours and minutes, and use that to bind to the drop down list.

Comment: Note that this line `var item = ddStartHours...` could throw an exception.  You want to wrap that a round an exception block.